# php can't request var on jquery mobille

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I have 3 pages, page A with jQuery mobile script:

```
<form id="form5" name="form5" method="post" action="jsearch-email.php">
<input type="search" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Search email only" />
</form>
```

page B even no jquery mobile script, jquery style exists:

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$k == 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {     
?>
<form name="form<?php echo $k; ?>" id="form<?php echo $k; ?>" data-ajax="false" method="post" action="jsearch-email-action.php">
    <input type='hidden' name='cid' value='<?php echo $row[0] ?>'>

    <?php echo $row[1]==1 ? "<input type='checkbox' name='unsubscribe' value='1' checked='checked'>" : "<input type='checkbox' name='unsubscribe' value='1'>" ?>
    <?php echo $row[2]==1 ? "<input type='checkbox' name='invalid' value='1' checked='checked'>" : "<input type='checkbox' name='invalid' value='1'>" ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php                                       
    $k++;
}
?>
```

page C:

```
$cid = $_REQUEST['cid'];
echo $cid;
```

`$cid` gets nothing when page B in jQuery style, but I want it to be in jQuery style. After I refresh page B, page B shows basic html style, `$cid` can receive data in page B.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: What is "jquery style"? You didn't post any jquery code here.

Comment: in page A, I added 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

in page B, i haven't added the above code

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
<form id="form5" name="form5" method="post" action="jsearch-email.php">
```

to this

```
<form id="form5" name="form5" method="post" data-ajax="false" action="jsearch-email.php">
```